# Dynamics 365 - Whitespace issue while creating a Notes

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

In dynamics 365 CE 9.1,  when I create Notes, the extra whitespace is getting added automatically as below -
[image]

If I edit the note and save the note text again then the whitespace disappears but on a refresh of the page, the whitespace gets added automatically.

Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Notes has always been an troublesome within CRM especially w.r.t CSS and all.
Even I have the same issue. Any Reason NO :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce your scenario. What browser are you using? Can you share a screenshot of your Activities Tab Properties?

Comment: If this happens in vanilla CRM as well, then create a MS ticket.